# Getting image path from SQlite db and setting image in ImageView in new Activity

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview, android-cursoradapter

I have been struggling with this problem for the last few days and still haven't found the right way to solve it (I've also checked a lot of similar issues here is StackOverflow but none of them helped me). 
So here is my problem: I have an activity in which I have an ImageView , which I made to take an image from the gallery when I click it . Here everything works fine and I see my image in the ImageView . After that, I save the imagePath of the image I've chosen from my gallery and put it in my SQLite database . Then I have CustomCursorAdapter class which extends CursorAdapter and then I want to somehow retrieve the imagePath with the cursor from SQLite and set the image I picked in another activity.

P.S: I don't know if that is programmatically possible but I assume so .I've done the thing I am asking for using SimpleCursorAdapter, but there things are way easier and my assignment is to use CustomCursorAdapter ! I will show parts of my code below so it's easier to explain what exactly it is that I want to achieve:

Here I Set the image in ImageView of my first activity after decoding the String

```
picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.questionImageView);
picture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
```

Then here I retrieve the imagePath from gallery and put it in SQlite

```
//retrieving imagePath
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
}
//Put imagePath in SQlite
Player player = new Player(playerName,playerLastName,playerEmail,playerDescription,imagePath);
```

Then I'm losing it here : This is in my CustomCursorAdapter class: This should somehow take the imagePath from SQlite db and set it myabe as drawable or I dont know how exactly in the ImageView of my other Activity

```
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      ImageView playerPicture = (ImageView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.questionImageView);
      //this here is not working apparently - I have a placeholder for when no image is picked from gallery and when i use the code bellow it disappears and the ImageView is just blank !
      playerPicture.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(
           cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PLAYER_PICTURE)));
 }
```

If more code is required (for example from my database just let me now and i will post it)
Thanks in advance ! I will appreciate examples in code ! :)

Comment: Storing image path. And retrieving  `cursor.getInt(
           cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PLAYER_PICTURE))` int value. Use `cursor.getString()` to retrieve imagepath.

Comment: It does not work , it says that only int can be used